# AWS EC2 Application Load Balancer redirecting HTTP site to https://example.com:80

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer

So I've got the EC2 up and running just fine, Application Load Balancer with both HTTP and HTTPS listeners (plus security group inbound rules), an alias record that points to the load balancer, and a lovely SSL certificate.  And actually, everything is working fine, save for one *tiny* problem.

When navigating to the root, unsigned site, which *should* redirect from "mysite.com" to "https://example.com", it's actually redirecting to "https://example.com:80" which is...problematic.

If you manually type in the HTTPS protocol, or use [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com), or go to mysite.com/whatever, it transfers to the HTTPS protocol without a hitch.  It's *only* when attempting to navigate to the *base* URL without manually assigning the HTTPS before the non-qualified host name that things get wonky.

```
**Again, just to avoid long lines:**
https://example.com - *works perfectly*
example.com/thingy - *works perfectly*
www.example.com - *works perfectly*
example.com - *laughs at me and changes the url to https://example.com:80*
```

Running a standard AWS Linux EC2 instance, nothing special, so if someone points out that I just need to change a setting in the Apache setup somewhere, I'll happily laugh at myself and thank them profusely.

I have tried completely tearing down the load balancer, listeners, certificate, and rebuilding it all from scratch to make sure I didn't miss any steps in there, but the result was exactly the same.

[Listeners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNkyb.png)

Comment: Share your redirect configuration

Comment: Are you doing the redirect in the load balancer or from the http server on the instance?

Comment: The redirect is built into the load balancer with the listeners (configuration image added to the post).  HTTP is redirecting to HTTPS://#{host}:443/#{path}?#{query} as a 301 (tried 302, just for fun, and had the same result), and HTTPS forwards to the target group.

Comment: Check your listeners redirection as well as target groups. See if your ec2 is correctly configured as listener in target groups